# X509Certificate2 constructor issues

Tags: x509certificate, x509certificate2

I have a pfx file. When I use the file stream to read this pfx file.
When I create the X509Certificate2 with just giving the raw bytes, it works.
But when I try to create the X509Certificate2 with the password and the flags I get an exception saying "The specified network password is incorrect".

The second X509Certificate2 construction fails with the exception : "The specified network password is incorrect" though the password is correct.

```
using (FileStream stream = new FileStream(@"D:\MyKey.pfx", FileMode.Open))
{
    int length = (int)stream.Length;
    byte[] certBytes = new byte[length];
    stream.Read(certBytes, 0, length);

    X509Certificate2 finalCert0 = new X509Certificate2(certBytes);
    X509Certificate2 finalCert1 = new X509Certificate2(certBytes, "venki", X509KeyStorageFlags.Exportable | X509KeyStorageFlags.PersistKeySet);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just had the same experience, I deleted the certificate file and re-copied the file over and it worked. I restored the old file and it failed in the same way.  Comparing the files revealed the files were drastically different, some how the file had been corrupted.